# AutoComplete not working in Apache ISIS Action

Tags: java, apache, autocomplete, isis

I have following method:

```
@Action(semantics = SemanticsOf.SAFE)
@ActionLayout(named = "Find alphabet Soup by Letter", bookmarking = BookmarkPolicy.AS_ROOT)
@MemberOrder(name = "Menu soups", sequence = "7")
public List<SomeObject> findByLetter(@ParameterLayout(named = "letter") final String letter) {
    return container.allMatches(new QueryDefault<SoupObject>(SoupObject.class, "findSoupQuery", "letter", letter)); 
}
```

I want that the Input-field for the parameter `letter` is a dropdown-list with autoCompletion.
So I added the autoComplete function:

```
public Collection<String> autoComplete0FindByLetter(@MinLength(3) String search) {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();     
    SoupFinder soupFinder = new SoupFinder();
    List<SoupObject> soups = soupFinder.findByLetter(search);
    for (SoupObject tmpSoup : soups) {
        ret.add(tmpSoup.getName(());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

So my problem is now: When I use the function `findByLetter` in the Wicked UI there is no dropdown field for the parameter `letter`.
Why is there no dropdown field respectively why does the autoComplete function not work. Did I forget something?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autocomplete only works with entities/view models, not with values.  Which kind-of makes sense: the point of autoComplete is to do a lookup of existing entities.  For strings, you can use choices, but not autoComplete.

I'm not sure if this is properly documented ... until I looked into it, I too thought that your code looked correct.

The closest you can get to the behaviour you are after is to use a very simple view model as a wrapper around the string, eg:

```
@ViewModel 
public class Choice {
    @Getter @Setter
    private String value;
}
```

and return a list of those.

Comment: Nice to know, that it only works with entities/view models. I wrapped the String into an own entity and then I could use the dropdown. Thank you for your advice!